# XML-AS3 Photo Gallery

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

How should i structure my XML if I wish to do a photo gallery in AS3 with categories?

Should I do it this way?

```
<gallery>
  <category>
  <name>..</name>
  <description>...</description>
  <pic>..</pic>
  <pic>..</pic>
  </category>

  <category>
  .......
  </category>
</gallery>
```

Or should I just put the different level of categories in different XML?

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it setup above is perfectly fine. There is no need to seperate it into multiple XML's.

Answer (score 0):

http://flashcommander.org/photoembed

check this i hope it will help you.......

Comment: you can download source code from this link.....http://flashcommander.org/downloads

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.